# How to get the std::fill function to work with a std::map?

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to use the `std::fill` function from the algorithm library to fill in '-' in the second part of the pair. Is this possible to achieve?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
int main()
{
    std::map<int, unsigned char> board(10);

    // What I want the std::fill to do the equivalent of  
    for (auto& cell : board) {
        cell.second = '-';
    }

    // What I've tried:
    std::fill(board.begin(), board.end(), [&](auto &pair){pair.second = '-';});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fill` assigns to each element of the range it is called on, whereas you want to assign to the values of those elements (key-value pairs). From C++20 you can use the `ranges::views::values` range adaptor:

```
std::ranges::fill(std::ranges::views::values(board), '-');
```

If you can't use C++20, your code will work by changing `fill` to `for_each`:

```
std::for_each(board.begin(), board.end(), [&](auto &pair){pair.second = '-';});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! Do I need to add any includes?

Comment: `std::for_each` is in `<algorithm>`, which you're including already. The ranges facilities are in `<ranges>`, if available.

Comment: I've tried putting Visual Studio 2019 in the latest C++, I don't think it supports it yet, but the std::for_each is great! Thanks very much!